# Find the largest number from a string using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable string like:

```
var myString = "857nano620348splitted3412674relation5305743";
```

How do I find the largest number from this?

I have tried like the below without any success.

```
var matches = myString.match(/d+/g);
```

Comment: Essentially, find all matches with your regex, sort the matches numerically (and or find the max in the list), output largest.

Comment: Other than the challenge of solving this... I have to wonder... why do you need to do this?

Comment: @scunliffe I'm a newbie and a random thought came in. Sorry If I broke any rules of asking question.

Comment: What does the variable name `xmr` stand for, or is it totally arbitrary?

Comment: @CodeDecode that's totally fine... I was just wondering if this was solving a real world code problem.

Comment: @scunliffe nice of you. But I do one day solve a real world code problem if I get there.

Comment: would 857 be treated as 857 or 8 5 7?

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be "what is the most concise set of expressions that can extract the largest number from an arbitrary string?" Unless you're parsing a string with a *regular* structure then invariably you'll need more than RegEx since it alone doesn't understand magnitudes, just character sequences.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'd go for

```
var myString = "857nano620348splitted3412674relation5305743";
var largest  = Math.max.apply(null, myString.match(/\d+/g));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6GXw2/2/)

`myString.match(/\d+/g)` returns an array of the numbers, and using `Math.max.apply(scope, array)` returns the largest number in that array.

Comment: I think this answer alone can take adeneo to 100k :)

Comment: Yeah that did helped. Unfortunately have to wait another 7 mins to accept the answer.

Comment: @ErikAllik - It's usually just luck, some great answers are never upvoted and forgotten, while sometimes a simple concise *working* answer is upvoted a lot, and sometimes even non working answers are upvoted a lot. It's a strange place, here on SO.

Comment: @anubhava - unfortunately, there's a daily limit of 200 rep, so probably not!

Comment: Yes I know about that 200 limit but it might get you a gold badge soon

Comment: At the speed at which it was getting upvoted it won't take long :)

Comment: @Erik Allik: this question is featured in "hot questions" of Stack Exchange, increasing its visibility.

Comment: That was short and sweet! +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var numArray = xmr.match(/\d+/g); //this will store all numbers from xmr to numArray.

numArray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});

var largest = numArray[numArray.length - 1];
```

Comment: There's one problem, `array.sort` doesn't sort numerically like that, so the array isn't really sorted the right way.

Comment: It's because the `array.sort()` converts each element to a string and sorts by lexicographic order.  This approach could still work with a custom sort function supplied to `array.sort()` to perform numeric sorting.

Comment: yeah you are absolutely right....to make it descending u can change function to 'function(a,b){return b-a}'......

Comment: +1, now it works! As a sidenote, you could do `var largest = numArray.pop();`, looks prettier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution to find the largest number from a string using a regular expression:

```
var myString ="857nano620348splitted3412674relation5305743";

Math.max(...myString.match(/\d+/g))`
```

Comment: Hi! Although must of the times, code might seem self explanatory, is good to provide some explanation, to how this is solving the question.

Comment: @Erubiel Thank you . i will add explanation form next time